# MongoDB production AUTH FAILED

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mlab

I'm trying to connect my server to my MongoDB database in production,

But When I try to do that :

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://user:randompassword@ds011452.mlab.com:11452/dbname?authSource=dbWithUserCredentials");
```

I get a

```
connection error: { [MongoError: auth failed] name: 'MongoError', ok: 0, errmsg: 'auth failed', code: 18 }
```

note : my dbname is the same as the username...

Any IDeas ?

Comment: check your username and password. does your password contains `@` or some characters that require `\` escape character?

Comment: Same issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've find my answer :

I've upgraded `mongoDB` to the `3.0 version`,

and after that I've upgraded `mongoose` to the > 4.3.0 version

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/compatibility.html

and It works !

edit :

after update mongoDB to 3.0
(I used `brew`)

```
package.json  
->
  "dependencies": {
    "mongoose": "~4.3.0",
    ...
```

then `npm install`